# converting from varchar to date not returning values from database

Tags: sql

```
WHERE
  (mf.FarmCode = @FarmCode or  @FarmCode is null) and
  (mf.BirdTypeCode = @FarmType or  @FarmType is null or @FarmType = 'ALL') and
  (f.ftrn_cdat > = Convert (datetime, @FromDate,103) or  @FromDate is null) and
  (f.ftrn_cdat < = Convert (datetime, @FromDate, 103) or  @ToDate is null)
```

the above where clause return all rows needed when the parameters are dates, but they need to be varchar for use in reporting services, no errors get thrown but no rows are returned, dates inputted in dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: Reporting services cannot handle date parameters ?!?

Comment: This looks like SQL server. Why is @FromDate is not a DateTime? Your query doesn't make much sense with >= and < =. It boils down to =.

Comment: @CetinBasoz i think he mean `>= @FromDate` and `<= @ToDate`. My guess is that he copy pasted it and forgot to correct it.

Comment: Try to change `(f.ftrn_cdat < = Convert (datetime, @FromDate, 103) or  @ToDate is null)` to `(f.ftrn_cdat < = Convert (datetime, @ToDate, 103) or  @ToDate is null)`. As the others commented, that might be the cause.

Comment: you were right guys thanks, cant believe ive been looking at that for close to an hour and didt see it

Comment: @TonnerMààn, I got he used spaces in > = to paste here, but it doesn't make sense I mean. Why would you say x >= y and x <= y instead of simply x = y?

Answer (score 1):

As they found in the comments was checking against from date twice